# How to pass the generic class type in java

Tags: java, generics

I have a pre-defined class called

```
ParameterList<Recipient_Type,Subject_Type> {
//some code here...
}
```

which is generic to take recipient type and subject type. I have an object called correspondence which has got setter methods for setting different kind of subjects like

```
correspondence.setSubject1((Subject1)subject)
correspondence.setSubject2((Subject2)subject).
```

And similar methods for setting different kind of recipients like

```
correspondence.setRecipient1((Recipient1)recipient),  
correspondence.setRecipient2((Recipient2)recipient), 
correspondence.setRecipient3((Recipeint3)recipient).
```

So basically I have 2 different subject types and 3 different kind of recipients. Till this part of code I can not change anything because its some existing framework code.

Now I have a following method which takes my correspondence object as a parameter and need to instantiate ParameterList class passing the correct subject and recipient type. There will be only one subject and recipient set on correspondence object. So in the below method

```
public void doTheJob(Correspondence correspondence){
  //How do I instantiate the ParameterList class provided subject can be any one of the two 
  //and recipient can be any one of the three.
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer seeing your code rather than reading a description of it ;)

Comment: is my problem statement looking better now...

Answer (score 0):

You can't decide the generic type at runtime, because generics are used mainly at compile time. So in case you don't know the exact type parameter, use `?`

Comment: Do you mean to change ParameterList<Recipient_Type, Subject_Type> to ParameterList<?,?>.

Comment: No. But when you instantiated use `?`

Comment: If I will be using '?' while instantiating 'ParameterList', how am I passing the right type of subject and recipient. While instantiating it should take the right subject and recipient type. Correct? Thats the whole idea.

Comment: what's the 'right' subject type? If it is known only at runtime, generics are not suitable for that

Comment: You can't instantiate generics using `?`

Comment: @Kublai Khan true, that's only the declaration. The instantiation will require `<Object>`

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

- Use `?`, as Bozho has said
- Use the (slightly) more specific `? extends WrapperBean`
- Refactor (if possible) so that all `SubjectN` classes inherit a common supertype and all `RecipientN` classes inherit a common supertype

Comment: How Subject1 will inherit Subject_Type? Subject1 is a class and Subject_Type is the generic type parameter of different class.

Comment: Is there any interface or supertype which all Subjects inherit?  Is there any interface or supertype which all Recipients inherit?

Comment: Yes, both Subject and Recipients inherit from a super type called WrapperBean.

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly.